# Why is the title spelled as Terra Formars?

Tags: terra-formars

Why is it that Terra Formars is spelled as Terra Formars and not *Terraformars* or *Terra for Mars*, while the technology to transform inhabitable planet into a habitable planet is called *Terraforming* and the noun is *terraformer* ([Oxford Reference](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/terraform))?

Was there any particular reason mentioned by the creator of the series for this way of spelling or is it just on a whim?

Comment: The "Terraformars", while the obvious breakdown being "Terra for Mars", was the name given to the evolved roaches on Mars, this label was created after the first manned mission to mars after the terraformers were sent there. They were all killed after they managed to send back a warning message. After that, people on Earth labelled them "TerraforMARS". Don't think there's any official citation for the reason for the name, but there is another story by the author named "Terra for Police"